# Playframework 1.2.* EventStream, @PostUpdate and @PostPersist

Tags: jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have an application where some requests allow modifying some entities and a request that blocks until a modification is performed (to notify the changes clientside)

I did the following:

```
@Entity
class TheEntity extends Model {

    public static Collection<TheEntity> getLastEntities(after) {
       //finds the entities where the `lastUpdateTimestamp` is greater than `after`
       return TheEntity.find("byLastUpdateTimestampGreaterThan", after).fetch();
    }

    @PostUpdate
    @PostPersist
    private void notifyChannel() {
        lastUpdateTimestamp = System.currentTime();
        Job asyncNotifier = new Job() {
            @Override
            public void doJob() throws Exception {
                //we manage the updates. the message channel trigs the channel
                MyChannel.publish(AcEvent.this);
            }

        };
        asyncNotifier.now();
    }
}
```

Now, I have a controller that listens to the channel

```
public static void listenMessageUpdate(Long after,Long blockDuration) {
    Collection<TheEntity> evts = MyChannel.getLast(after);
    if (evts.isEmpty()) {
        Timeout timeout = F.Timeout(blockDuration*1000);
        Promise<TheEntity> nextFlt = MyChannel.nextEvent();
        Either<Timeout, TheEntity> await = await(F.Promise.waitEither(
                timeout, nextFlt));

        evts = TheEntity.getLastEntities(after);
    }
    renderJSON(TheEntity.toJson(evts));
}
```

In fact, the TheEntity.getLastEntities(after) will not return the recently modified or created element in PROD mode.

After investigation, the transaction is not committed when the eventstream is notified, there fore, the entity is not up to date in the DB

**what is the best practice to be notified on each entity modification?**

Comment: could you change `asyncNotifier.now();` to `asyncNotifier.in(5)` so you can delay the job initialization

Comment: @hzog In fact it is a very bad idea. In production mode, I've got this non-deterministic error when using postgresql:    

     2014-11-29 18:46:04,239 ERROR ~ an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)   

I finally discard the _PostUpdate_ annotation annotation and superseeded the save method to call notifyChannel()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line `MyChannel.publish(AcEvent.this);`

In fact, `AcEvent.this` is an entity inside a session+transaction.  `listenMessageUpdate` belongs to an other session+transaction, therefore, access is not deterministic. The solution is to pass to the publish something that is not an entity. Cannot be neither an ID, because it may not have been flushed (transaction not committed when `listenMessageUpdate` executes).

We have to pass an IO structure with the useful fields